# Слушать порт по udp в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Подскажите как принимать сообщения по udp (в моём случае это 514 порт, syslog) Приведите какой-нибудь простенький пример на QT4. В сети нашёл примеры только на UDP. Если что в Qt новичок. Спасибо.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html не оно?

Comment: Да, это оно, но т.к. я новичок, хотелось бы какой-нибудь пример.

Comment: @НиколаКривошея http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#details

Comment: Пример там ровно под словом **Example:**.